# Using do notation with if/else

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use `do notation` to only return a list element if it's `even`:

```
ghci> do { x <- [1,2,3]; if (even x) [x] else []}
<interactive>:43:36: parse error on input `else'
```

What am I doing wrong?

In addition, please note if this code is non-idiomatic.

Comment: what about "then" ? :P

Comment: yep - simple mistake. thanks, 'felipez'. Post for credit or shall I delete this?

Comment: I'm not sure, just don't worry. It happens to me all the time!

Comment: This question should probably be closed, as it is only a typographical mistake.

Comment: A list comprehension is more idiomatic than `do` notation here: `[ x | x <- [1,2,3], even x ]`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the "then".
Also, i'm not really sure which Monad is this..

```
do { x <- [1,2,3]; if (even x) then [x] else []}
```

Comment: `[] a` (or rather, `[a]`), is a Monad. You can type `:i []` in GHCi and receive: `instance Monad [] -- Defined in GHC.Base`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Didn't know [] become Monad in "do" constructions